# How can i calculate the scroll distance from sticky start to sticky end?

Tags: javascript, html, css, math

I have a sticky container on my html page like this:

```html
<style>
  section {
    height: 250vh;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
</style>

<section>
  <div class="sticky">
     <!-- content goes here -->
  </div>
</section>
```

I want to calculate the scroll distance from sticky start to sticky end, so i know, how many pixels i need to scroll before the my sticky container no longer sticks to the top of the viewport.

I tried this calculation:

```js
let stickyEnd = 1 // 1 means 100%;
let stickyLength = window.innerHeight / 250 * 100; //1690px (convert 250vh in px)
let stickyEnd = stickyEnd * stickyLength / 1; //1690px
```

So the result is, i need to scroll `1690px` before sticky container no longer sticks to the top of the viewport, but this is incorrect. When i scroll `1690px` from top of my viewport the sticky container is 100% invisible.

So what do i need to change, to get the correct scroll distance?

Comment: if you provide a working example. It would be easy to provide a solution

Comment: @MrKhan i am working with svelte framework. I could provide you an REPL. Would that be okay?

Comment: nope that wont be beneficial for me. Try elaborating a bit more. What i understood by your question is that the sticky header is place somewhere below and is not sticky yet. You scroll to it then it becomes sticky. What you need to know at what position will it stop being sticky.

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct calculation in this case

```js
let stickyOffsetHeight = document.querySelector('.sticky').offsetHeight;
let stickyEnd = 1 // 1 means 100%;
let stickyLength = window.innerHeight / 250 * 100; //1690px (convert 250vh in px)
let stickyEnd = (stickyEnd * stickyLength / 1) - stickyOffsetHeight;
```

**Short Explanation:**

In the above example, the parent of sticky element is `250vh` so that means, that the sticky element has not a height of `250vh`. The height is based on the content inside the sticky element. So we need to deducted the `stickyOffsetHeight` and we get the correct result;